# Programmatically scroll to end of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-nestedscrollview

I have implemented [TapTargetView](https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView) library to my app.

After passing a certain element, I need to focus on the next view which is outside the screen at this moment:

```
@Override
public void onSequenceStep(TapTarget lastTarget) {
  if (lastTarget.id() == 7) {
     flavorContainer.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
     flavorContainer.requestFocus();
  }
}
```

Everything was fine, before I added the ad unit at the bottom of the screen. So now the necessary element is displayed behind the ads.

[image]

Method **requestFocus()** scrolls layout only to the necessary view was visible but not to the end of screen.

[image]

I need a method that scrolls the contents of the screen to the **VERY END**, not just what would the necessary view become visible on the screen. Is it possible?

[image]

**Layout structure**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<LinearLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView> 
<LinearLayout> 
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView> 
<LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout> 
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView> 
</LinearLayout> 
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView> 
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 62):

You have two possible solutions with pros and cons.

**First**

Use the method `fullScroll(int)` on `NestedScrollView`. `NestedScrollView` must be drawn before using this method and the focus will be lost on the `View` that gained it before.

```
nestedScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        nestedScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```

**Second**

Use the method `scrollBy(int,int)`/`smoothScrollBy(int,int)`. It requires much more code, but you will not lose the current focus:

```
nestedScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        final int scrollViewHeight = nestedScrollView.getHeight();
        if (scrollViewHeight > 0) {
            nestedScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            final View lastView = nestedScrollView.getChildAt(nestedScrollView.getChildCount() - 1);
            final int lastViewBottom = lastView.getBottom() + nestedScrollView.getPaddingBottom();
            final int deltaScrollY = lastViewBottom - scrollViewHeight - nestedScrollView.getScrollY();
            /* If you want to see the scroll animation, call this. */
            nestedScrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, deltaScrollY);
            /* If you don't want, call this. */
            nestedScrollView.scrollBy(0, deltaScrollY);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It's working fine,
but i want to scroll my screen till recycler last item is is possible?, if yes then how?

Comment: method-1 is working, but as you said, i'm losing focus. Method-2 is not working for me.

Answer (score 13):

For me this worked best. It scrolls to the bottom.

```
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollView.getChildAt(0).height)
// scrollview has always only one child
```

Comment: adding duration, even make this more smoother.

scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollView.getChildAt(0).height, 1000)